# How to diagnose a hanging MySQL UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple UPDATE statement running on a MySQL 5.6.34 database that's seemingly hanging. The statement only updates a single row with a timestamp and looks like:

```
UPDATE mytable SET last_updated='2017-05-31 02:13:43' WHERE id=123;
```

Yet after an hour, this was still running.

Running `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;` doesn't show any other processes accessing the table, so I don't think it's a deadlock. I tried killing and re-running the process, but it still hangs.

What other reasons would cause a simple UPDATE statement like this to hang? How do I diagnose this?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `slow_query_log = 1` (if >=5.6.1) or 
`log_slow_queries = 1`(if <5.6.1) and 
`slow_query_log_file = /path/to/logfile` and `long_query_time = 0` in my.cnf, then restart mysql and have a look at the logfile. I won't keep it on on production envs, such a logging is a performance killer and may result in bad things if you are on heavy load. It may also get quickly very big as long_query_time 0 results in logging everything, so "/path/to" should have plenty of free space.

Answer (score 0):

The issue forced me to restart the server, which corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If its a InnoDB table, `show engine innodb status` should give an indication if its waiting on a lock.

A cause for it still to be running is a rather large table and that `id` isn't a primary or secondary key on the table.